# WCF timedout waiting for System.Diagnostics.Process to finish

Tags: wcf

We have a WCF Service deployed on Windows Server 2003 that handles file transfers. When file is in Unix format, I am converting it to Dos format in the initialization stage using System.Diagnostics.Process (.WaitForExit()). Client calls the service:

```
    obj_DataSenderService = New DataSendClient()
    obj_DataSenderService.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DatasenderServiceOperationTimeout"), 0)
    str_DataSenderGUID = obj_DataSenderService.Initialize(xe_InitDetails.GetXMLNode)
```

This works fine, however for large files the conversion takes more than 10 minutes and I am getting exception:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The socket
>   connection was aborted. This could be
>   caused by an error processing your
>   message or a receive timeout being
>   exceeded by the remote host, or an
>   underlying network resource issue.
>   Local socket timeout was
>   '00:59:59.8749992'.

I tried configuring both client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
   <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IDataSend" closeTimeout="01:00:00"
                    openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
     <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
     <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
     </security>
    </binding>
   </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:4000/DataSenderEndPoint"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IDataSend"
                contract="IDataSend" name="NetTcpBinding_IDataSend">
    <identity>
     <servicePrincipalName value="host/localhost" />
     <!--<servicePrincipalName value="host/axopwrapp01.Corp.Acxiom.net" />-->
    </identity>
   </endpoint>
  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

And service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IDataSend" closeTimeout="01:00:00"
                    openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

but without luck. In the Service trace viewer I can see:

Close process timed out waiting for service dispatch to complete.

with stack trace:

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceChannelManager.CloseInput(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceContextManager.CloseInput(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnClose(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close()
>   DataSenderService.DataSender.OnStop()
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.DeferredStop()
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server,
>   Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]&
>   outArgs)
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(RuntimeMethodHandle
>   md, Object[] args, Object server,
>   Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]&
>   outArgs)
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.DoAsyncCall()
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object
>   o)
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object
>   userData)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object
>   userData)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback
>   tpWaitCallBack)
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object
>   state)

Many thanks
Bartek

Answer (score 0):

Does your WCF service actually return the file contents? If so, perhaps you should use WCF's capability for streaming, and change the line endings from Unix to DOS style as you stream it, rather than processing the file and then returning it as you are currently doing. Read in each line, and then stream it out with the correct line ending.

Comment: Yes, the WCF service indeed returns the file contents. The problem is that those files are actually flat file databases and in some circumstances have to be sorted before sending (records are sent in the real time one by one). The sort lib however (from 3rd party) fails to sort files in unix format - that's why conversion was required.

Thanks
Bartek